# How to get the label in the material-ui text field to the right?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, textfield

I'm using `material-ui` and `typescript` for my react project (rtl layout) and i don't know how to get the label of text field to the right?

[image]

Comment: Follow this [link](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/#opting-out-of-rtl-transformation)

Comment: @tarzenchugh The placeholder is on the right, but not labels!

Comment: Please add code to reproduce the issue with clear expectation.

Comment: <TextField variant="outlined" placeholder="نام" label="تست"/>          And the above image is clear, i wanna get the label of text field to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `jss-rtl` to support rtl for css. This library provides its `Provider` to support rtl in any library.

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from "jss";
import rtl from "jss-rtl";
import JssProvider from "react-jss/lib/JssProvider";
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

// Configure JSS
const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });

// Custom Material-UI class name generator.
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

function RTL(props) {
  return (
    <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      {props.children}
    </JssProvider>
  );
}

export default RTL;
```

Then in your main app use this provider.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <RTL>
    <Demo />
  </RTL>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

**Working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-tdz8p)**

Comment: thank you, but i got error in this line: `const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl() ] });` and the **error**: Argument of type '{ plugins: (JSSPlugin | { onProcessStyle(style: any, rule: any, sheet: any): any; })[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<JSSOptions>'.Types of property 'plugins' are incompatible.

Comment: For me its working fine --> Did you see [codesanbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-tdz8p). Did you install `react-jss` and `jss-rtl` libraries?

Comment: yes, but still not working.. I see that it works for you

Comment: by the way, i'm using Typescript

Answer (score 3):

Found a better way **without** external libraries.

```
export const theme = createTheme({
components: {
   MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            left: 'inherit',
            right: '1.75rem',
            transformOrigin: 'right',
       },
   },
},
   MuiOutlinedInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
          notchedOutline: {
            textAlign: 'right',
          },
      },
   },
},
})
```