# Place material ui Text filed label on the top right of the Border instead of the left

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi i am trying to make a textfiled for Arabic Text as the Arabic text is positioned form right to left there for i also want to place the label at to top right corner but not able to do that
The styling i am applying is

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    formControl: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        transform: 'translate(0, 24px) scale(1)',
      },
    labelRoot: {
        right: "20px",
      },
      shrink: {
        transformOrigin: "top right",
        transform:"translateX(50px)"
    }
}));
```

and my textfield is

```
<TextField
                    style={{ direction: "rtl" }}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: { root: classes.labelRoot, shrink: classes.shrink }
                      }}
                    label={t("Ad Title (eg: Toyota Camry 2018 for Sale)")}
                    variant="outlined"
                    fullWidth
                    onChange={ev => setData({
                        ...data,
                        title: ev.target.value
                    })}
                    value={data ? data.title : ''}
                    required
                />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the label in the material-ui text field to the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56198736/how-to-get-the-label-in-the-material-ui-text-field-to-the-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to `dir="rtl"` to `body`.

As per MUI [documentation](https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/#right-to-left), You can do this.

1. HTML
   Make sure the dir attribute is set on the body, otherwise native components will break:

```
    <body dir="rtl"></body>
```

As an alternative to the above, you can also wrap your application in an element with the dir attribute:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div dir="rtl">
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This can be helpful for creating components to toggle language settings in the live application.

2. Theme
   Set the direction in your custom theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  direction: 'rtl',
});
```

If you look into the `MUI` [documentation](https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/#right-to-left) it specifically mentions the direction change and a similar experience is implemented with the mui documentation theme as well.

In addition to this,

Comment: What i want is that the empty space in the border should be at right like in that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56198736/how-to-get-the-label-in-the-material-ui-text-field-to-the-right and currently what i am having i am having my label at the top right but not the empty space shown in this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5I8BLsmalDsmbj_FXtqjnPq_hMZORTc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Abdul, 
That's what this example will solve as per the documentation. Do check the demo go to this link. https://mui.com/components/text-fields/. Click on settings on top right and choose the direction. That will change the example direction in the text field demo on the page.

Comment: That is what i needed exactly but noting in the code changed to show me how i can do that

Comment: That's what I have mentioned in the answer. 

Click on this link to find the answer. https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/#right-to-left

Comment: Hi i want to give you some deep insights so you can solve my issue i have given the detailed insight view of the code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69632248/not-able-to-align-the-material-ui-components-from-right-to-left thsi link

Comment: your solution worked for firefox but not for google so i want a little bit more help

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this simple example to change direction to the right.
make sure to install required packages in order for this to work : 
if you use npm :

```
npm install stylis-plugin-rtl @emotion/react @emotion/cache
```

if you use yarn :

```
yarn install stylis-plugin-rtl @emotion/react @emotion/cache
```

Make sure the dir attribute is set on the body, otherwise native components will break:

```
<body dir="rtl"></body>
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
// or import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';
import { prefixer } from 'stylis';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';

const theme = createTheme({
  direction: 'rtl', // Both here and <body dir="rtl">
});
// Create rtl cache
const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: 'muirtl',
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin],
});

export default function Direction() {
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div dir="rtl">
          <TextField label="Name" variant="standard" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

you can check the documentation here : [Mui RTL](https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/#right-to-left)