# Not able to align the material ui components from right to left

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, text-files

Hi I have a website that supports both English and Arabic I want to align the MUI text fields and dropdowns from right to left direction mainly the label of the text filed and the dropdowns are not styled properly. I am using the theme listed below.

```
const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: blue[500],
        light: blue[100],
        dark: blue[700]
      },
      secondary: {
        main: blue[300]
      },
      success: {
        main: green[400]
      }
    },
    typography: {
      "fontFamily": "Poppins",
    },
    overrides: {
      MuiTypography: {
        color: '#787878'
      },
      '& *': {
        fontFamily: "Poppins",
      },
    },
    direction: state.theme.direction,
  })
```

and in `App.js` my returned component is

```
<div>
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   {myComponentCode}
 </ThemeProvider>
</div>
```

I also want to mention that it works fine for Firefox but not for Google Chrome.

It's not placing the text filed label correctly on Chrome, I want it at the top right with empty space at the back.

[image: the display on Chrome]

[image: the display on Firefox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install additional plugin ([stylis-plugin-rtl](https://github.com/styled-components/stylis-plugin-rtl) for MUI v5 or [jss-rtl](https://github.com/alitaheri/jss-rtl) for MUI v4 ) and place it inside your `<ThemeProvider>`:

**MUI v5:**

```
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";

const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: "muirtl",
  stylisPlugins: [rtlPlugin]
});

...
return(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
          {children}
      </CacheProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
)
```

**Material UI v4**

```
import { create } from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// Configure JSS
const jss = create({ plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()] });

...
  return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
      {children}
    </StylesProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

[Working DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-textfield-mui-moebp?file=/src/App.js:453-690)

[Full guide MUI v5](https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/)

[Full guide Material UI v4](https://v4.mui.com/guides/right-to-left/)